# Updating MySQL field based on other fields added upon creation in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

With Facebook API discontinuing username retrieval, I need to create a username in Rails by adding together fields such as:

```
User.username = first_name + last_name + rand(99999)
```

Any idea on how to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find all users that you want to update, and iterate trough them. In this case i will update every user, in batches of 1000. Docs about [find_each](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html)

```
User.find_each do |user|
  username = "#{user.user_first_name}_#{user.last_name}_#{rand(99999)}"
  user.update_attribute(:username, username)
end
```

For new users, just add one before create callback, to your user model

```
before_create :generate_username

....

def generate_username
  begin
     self.username ="#{self.user_first_name}_#{self.last_name}_#{rand(99999)}"
  end while User.exists?(:username => self.username)
end
```